# how to declare a react ref in props function when using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to pass the refs from one component to a function passed in from another component as a prop, and I need to do it in typescript.

So the relevant code inside the child component is

```
class Login extends Component<IProps, IState>  {
    private emailRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
    private passRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

    constructor(props?) {
        super(props);
    }

    login = () => {
        const email = this.emailRef.current;
        const pass = this.passRef.current;
        this.props.login(email, pass);
    }
```

which is ok, but now inside of my IProps I should declare login.

And I can't figure out how to do it?

As an example

```
    interface IProps {
      login: (u: any, p: any) => any,
      errorMessage: ''
    }
```

obviously those anys are no good, and need to be replaced with something better. How do I specify that I am in fact going to be passing a react ref here?

Comment: `login: (u: HTMLInputElement, p: HTMLInputElement) => void`

Comment: ok - I thought the ref was a wrapping type that gave me some other properties, although I have to admit I didn't have any particular reason for that supposition.

Comment: ok that works, thanks!

Comment: oh of course I'd forgotten that "When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref created in the constructor with React.createRef() receives the underlying DOM element as its current property."  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1):

Declare in `constructor()` as,

```
 constructor(props?) {
        super(props);
        this.emailRef = React.createRef();
        this.passRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

Comment: Why? what is the necessity to define refs in the constructor? thought the question is not what you have answered

Comment: Yes correct, never used ref in class, always using in FC, but technically both work :)

Comment: in typescript using this.emailRef inside the constructor gives me error S2339: Property 'emailRef' does not exist on type 'THE COMPONENT TYPE'